# Sqlite DB Error - could not prepare statement

Tags: sqlite

I am getting following error on insert statement for sqlite DB

could not prepare statement (1 near "undefined": syntax error)

I tried 2 variations of insert, for both error is same

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Med(MedID) VALUES(?),";
sql += "['"+dataObj[i].MedID+"']";


var sql = "INSERT INTO Med(MedID) VALUES ('"+dataObj[i].MedID+"')";

tx.executeSql(sql);
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `"['"+dataObj[i].MedID+"']";` Square brackets should not be part of an identifier in SQL. You should print the final SQL string to see where the problem is.

Comment: what about the second code line.
And after printing the final sql is "INSERT INTO Med(MedID) VALUES(?),['10']";

Comment: There is no "undefined" in that SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to give parameters to an SQL statement is as follows:

```js
var sql = "INSERT INTO Med(MedID) VALUES (?)";
tx.executeSql(sql, [dataObj[i].MedID]);
```

Comment: var sql = "INSERT INTO Med(MedID) VALUES ('"+dataObj[i].MedID+"')";
tx.executeSql(sql);

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the space that is needed between the table name and the column names.

Try this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Med (MedID) VALUES ('"+dataObj[i].MedID+"')";
tx.executeSql(sql);
```

Make sure your dataObj[i].MedID is also defined. Add a console.log(sql) before your executeSql statement to check the command before using it.